# UITableView from NSMutableArray iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have an array with objects 1-10 (let's say). I want the cell.textLabel.text = 1,3,5,7... and I want the cell.detailtextLabel.text = 2,4,6,8...

How do I get the detail text to alternate?

Or, is there a better way? Make two mutableArrays and combine them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [yourlist objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row * 2)];
cell.detailtextLabel.text = [yourlist objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row * 2)+1];
```

Comment: +1 for a working solution, though from a design pov i recommend making two separate arrays, one for the main text and one for the detailtext

Comment: getting this error:  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'

Comment: scratch that do return [array count]/2 and you're good, thanks!